# How to add event to newborn element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have an event, which inserts on the page new DOM element.
How to add event to this new element?
My goal is: when user clicks on the input, old value should purge.
I have tried this:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    var newel = '<input type="text" value="test" />';
    $(newel).insertAfter($('a'));

});
$('input').on('focus', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
    $(this).val('');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WpyUf/
New event doesn't added to the element, why?

Comment: In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to jsFiddle. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what'd happen if jsFiddle went down in the future.

Comment: And what is it you're trying to do exactly. Adding an event to the new element can be done by delegating or just binding the event handler after the element is created, and what exactly is'nt working for you ?

Comment: When user clicks on the input, old value should purge.

Comment: Even when you use .on() the element you want to bind the event handler to must already exist in the DOM. So here the focus event handler will only be bound to input elements that already exist. If you want it to react dynamically you should use the syntax `$(parentElement).on('EVENT', 'SELECTOR', callback)` which will bind the EVENT handler to the (already existing) parent element and then delegate the event to an element below matching the SELECTOR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    var newel = '<input type="text" value="test" />';
    $(newel).insertAfter($('a'));
});
$(document).on('focus', 'input', function() {
    $(this).val('');
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WpyUf/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code Worked by changing `jQuery` version to `1.7.2`

This is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iMaverick/WpyUf/5/)

Comment: In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and don't just include a link to jsFiddle. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what'd happen if jsFiddle went down in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this.

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    var newel = '<input type="text" />';
    $(newel).insertAfter($('a')).bind('click', function() {alert("me");});
;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dadviegas/WpyUf/4/

Comment: In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and don't just include a link to jsFiddle. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what'd happen if jsFiddle went down in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    var newel = '<input type="text" />';
    $(newel).on("focus",function() { alert("hello")}).insertAfter($('a'));

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/wzKy7/)